# Можно ли из суммы или разности цифр одного числа составить другое число

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно написать функцию которая из суммы или разности цифр одного числа делает другое. Например 123 и 6. 1 + 2 + 3 = 6. Если вариантов как это сделать несколько, вывести все. Еще пример 1234 и 2. -1+2-3+4 = 2. Нужно использовать битовые операции обязательно. Я написал такой код и он работает когда числа можно сделать только из суммы, но из разности, например когда я ввожу 1234 и 2 выводит ['-2+3-4-']. Не хватает 1. Объясните как сделать правильно пожалуйста.

```
def num_combinations(a, n):
    f = []
    c = len(str(a))
    for k in range(1 << c):
        s = 0
        a1 = a
        i = 0
        p = ''
        while a1 != 0:
            ib = (k >> i) & 1
            if ib == 1:
                s += (a1 % 10) * ib
                p +=  '+' + str(a1 % 10)
            elif ib == 0:
                s -= (a1 % 10) * ib
                p += '-' + str(a1 % 10)
            i += 1
            a1 //= 10
        if s == n:
            f.append(p[-2::-1])
    return f
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написал так:

```
def num_combinations(a, n):
    digits = [int(i) for i in str(a)]
    result = []
    operators = ['-', '+']
    for i in range(1 << len(digits)):
        s = 0
        t = ''
        for j in range(len(digits)):
            if i & (1 << j):
                s += digits[j]
                t += '+' + str(digits[j])
            else:
                s -= digits[j]
                t += '-' + str(digits[j])
        if s == n:
            result.append(t)
    return result

print(num_combinations(1234, 2))
#['+1+2+3-4', '-1+2-3+4']
```

Если нам нужно использовать все цифры и у нас только знаки плюс и минус, то можно перебирать все варианты с помощью битовой записи, как вы сами и поняли. Далее, чтобы определить знак для определенной цифры, нужно посмотреть на соответствующий бит номера итерации. Чтобы это сделать используем `i & (1 << j)`.